# C# WP7 Button Pressed state throwing: "Invalid attribute value for property Background."

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, button, pressed

Error: "Invalid attribute value for property Background."

XAML:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        ....
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="/Images/home_2_click.png" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        ....
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971506/why-isnt-my-windows-phone-silverlight-rotation-animation-working/9972220#9972220 it maybe similar

Comment: Hi Roman, the answer below helped me, but yours led me to some cool animation related issues :) good for future ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you seems to apply background imag to a button during animation.
Certainly you are applying it in a wrong way.
you must do the following:

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="" />
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
</DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
```

This will certainly solvers your problem. And if it does, then please mark this as an accepted answer.
thanx